# How to automate program initialization through GUI

Tags: windows, ui-automation

We have a software that needs to get password to be initialized. Software is running on a build server (Windows 10) and used as part of the build process. Password resets after reboot or after RDP session. Therefore RDP access to the server is disabled and it's running VNC.

However, still we have a problem that once in a while server reboots and in this case someone needs to login to the server over VNC and to initialize the software by typing password in.

Is there any way that this process may be automated? Some QA tools that may be utilized for this puprpose?

Comment: If auto logon is set (find the instruction on SuperUser site), startup script can run on this server without alive VNC connection (in WIndows Task Scheduler by logon trigger). As an GUI automation library you can use pywinauto (need any Python on the server + `pip install pywinauto`). If you keep the server always logged in, maybe another trigger would be useful (from Jenkins slave if it's connected to Jenkins). But it must run not as a service (services can't access GUI).

Comment: Thanks! pywinauto is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: OK, great. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If auto logon is set (find the instruction on SuperUser site), startup script can run on this server without alive VNC connection (in Windows Task Scheduler by logon trigger). As an GUI automation library you can use pywinauto (need any Python on the server + `pip install pywinauto`). If you keep the server always logged in, maybe another trigger would be useful (from Jenkins slave if it's connected to Jenkins). But it must run not as a service (services can't access GUI).